# Add a substraction row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In this code, i would like to add a new row underneath the row `.Cells(6).Offset(1).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = newValues`. This row should be the results of a substraction between newValues and oldValues. this should be looped over each el. thanks a lot!

```
Dim RangeValues As Object 'global (or could use Static inside the event handler)
Dim startTime

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim elapsedTime As Double ' Stores the elapsed time
    Dim logSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oldValues As Variant, newValues As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long, numColumns As Long
    Dim i As Long, LogRanges, el
   

    'assuming all ranges to be logged are single-row and >1 cell...
    LogRanges = Array("N20:FB20", "N21:FB21", "N22:FB22", "N24:FB24", "N26:FB26", "N30:FB30", "N31:FB31", "N32:FB32", "N33:FB33", "N34:FB34", "N35:FB35", "N38:FB38", "N40:FB40", "N42:FB42", "N44:FB44", "N48:FB48", "N49:FB49", "N50:FB50")

    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "G11" 'G11 was selected
            ' Start the stopwatch and capture old values
            startTime = Now
            Set RangeValues = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For Each el In LogRanges 'capture current values from each range
                With Me.Range(el)
                    RangeValues(.Address) = .Value
                End With
            Next el
        Case "H11" 'H11 was selected
            ' Stop the stopwatch, capture new values, and log the information
            Set logSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log - Ratio")
            rowNum = logSheet.Cells(logSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 3

          ' Assuming the target sheet name is "TargetSheet" (replace with actual sheet name)

          ' Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ratios sommaire")


          For Each el In LogRanges
                With Me.Range(el)
                    oldValues = RangeValues(.Address)
                    newValues = .Value
                End With
                numColumns = UBound(oldValues, 2)
                        ' Add a new column for the subtraction results


                With logSheet.Rows(rowNum)
                    .Cells(1).Value = startTime
                    .Cells(1).Offset(1).Value = Now
                    .Cells(2).Resize(2).Value = Application.UserName
                    .Cells(3).Resize(2).Value = el 'range address
                    .Cells(4).Value = "OLD"
                    .Cells(5).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value  ' Retrieve value from row N and column 10
                    .Cells(6).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = oldValues
                    .Cells(4).Offset(1).Value = "NEW"
                    .Cells(5).Offset(1).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value  ' Retrieve value from row N and column 10
                    .Cells(6).Offset(1).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = newValues
               
                    End With
                rowNum = rowNum + 3
            Next el


    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
    Dim c As Range
    '...
    '...
    .Cells(6).Offset(1).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = newValues
    For Each c In .Cells(6).Resize(1, numColumns).Cells
        c.Offset(2).Value = c.Value - c.Offset(1).Value
    Next c
    '...
    '...
```

or using the source arrays (should be faster):

```
'...
'...
.Cells(6).Offset(2).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = ArrayDiff(newValues, oldValues)
'...
'...


'Subtract values in `arr2` from values in `arr1` and
'  return differences as an array
'The input arrays must be 2D and have the same dimensions
Function ArrayDiff(arr1, arr2)
    Dim arrRes, r As Long, c As Long, ubc As Long, ubr As Long, v1, v2
    ubr = UBound(arr1, 1)
    ubc = UBound(arr1, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To ubr, 1 To ubc)
    For r = 1 To ubr
        For c = 1 To ubc
            v1 = arr1(r, c)
            v2 = arr2(r, c)
            If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
                arrRes(r, c) = v1 - v2
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    ArrayDiff = arrRes
End Function
```

Comment: I'm trying it and the code is very slow. 5minutes to calculates and it overwrites certain of the previous rows.....Tim Collins

Comment: See edit above for a faster approach

Comment: Great it works amazing! i flagged it. Btw any chance you would know how to execute the following. In .Cells(5).Value =  `` the value associated with the row number of Me.Range(el) and column J `` ? thanks Tim Williams

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking - you already have `.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value` in your posted code

Comment: Yes, indeed.  The logic behind  ``.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value`` should work in theory, but for some reason it doesn't . Maybe you know of a different way to write it that could work. Tim Williams

Comment: What value does that fetch instead of the value in "J" ?

Comment: It doesn't pick up anything. The celle returns blank. Just so you know the original value is in a text format, maybe this affect it, i dont know.... Tim Williams

Comment: What do you get from `Debug.Print .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Address` ?

Comment: i get invalid or unqualified reference. Tim Williams

Comment: did you put that right above `.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value` ?

Comment: Yes, but it's fine i found another way without using VBA to get what i wanted, Thanks a lot for your help! Tim Williams